# Always show old logic of js

Tags: javascript, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.3

To load js I use this in my java file in Vaadin project:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@JavaScript("../../VAADIN/callback.js")


    UI.getCurrent().getPage().getJavaScript().execute("myFunction('" + providerGUID + "')");
```

and as result success call `myFunction` from js file. Nice.

But if I change content of `myFuncion` and rebuild project and refresh (C-F5) my page it's again show old content of javascript file.

P.S.
This not help

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(resourceCacheTime = 0, ui = UbUI.class, productionMode = false)
```

Comment: In some few cases it's not enough to reset with F5 or even CTRL-F5. Have you tried to really delete the cache in your browser? Or could it be perhaps a proxy in your your setting which stored some old stuff?

Comment: @Sascha delete the cache in your browser help me. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it's so easy but you think much too complicated ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some few cases it's not enough to reset with F5 or even CTRL-F5. Here helps to really delete the cache in your browser.

If you use Chrome than you can disable in preferences the cache while using DevTools. This helps me sometimes. The little loss of perfomance doesn't bother me for testing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a Java script caching issue. You can try CTRL-F5 or clear your browser cache.
It's always better to use browser incognito mode whenever making/testing java script code.